# Pasar el stdout y stderr a un archivo y stderr a otro archivo

Tags: bash, script, stdout

estoy haciendo un script en bash y quiero pasar el stderr y stdout a un solo archivo (output.log). Además, quiero pasar únicamente el stderr a otro archivo (error.log). Por pantalla tiene que mostrar los comandos que yo decida del script. Tipo hacer una checklist.

He conseguido hacerlo, pero tengo que ejecutar el script así:

`{ . sript.sh 2>&1 1>&3 | tee error.log; } > output.log 3>&1`

Y además, en cada comando que quiera mostrar, tengo que agregar al lado:

`| tee -a /dev/tty`

Además, el tput civis para ocultar el cursor no funciona correctamente al ejecutarlo de esa manera.

Lo ideal sería ejecutar el script sencillamente así:

`. script.sh`

Y que dentro del script ya se agregen la línea superior y elegir que comandos mostrar.

Puedo poner un ejemplo haciendo un ping. El ping no debe mostrarse:

```
echo "Haciendo ping..." | tee -a /dev/tty
if ! ping -c 3 google.es; then # Comprueba si el ping ha sido exitoso
  echo "Error al hacer ping" | tee -a /dev/tty
else
  echo "Ping realizado con éxito" | tee -a /dev/tty
fi
```

El output es:

```
Haciendo ping...
Ping realizado con éxito
```

Si para hacer una checklist alguien tiene otra sugerencia también lo agradezco, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un segundo código que mande llamar al primero:

```
#!/bin/bash

ejecutable="$1"
shift
argumentos="$@"

{ ./"$ejecutable" $argumentos 2>&1 1>&3 | tee error.log; } > output.log 3>&1
```

Si a este código lo haces ejecutable y lo llamas, por ejemplo `redireccionar.sh`, podrías hacer simplemente

```
./redireccionar.sh script.sh
```

y reutilizarlo para otros códigos. También puedes hacer una función para ahorrarte el `| tee` en cada línea dentro de tu código:

```
mensaje(){
   echo "$@" | tee -a /dev/tty
}
```

y, en lugar de `echo "texto" | tee -a /dev/tty` simplemente ejecutarías `mensaje "texto"`.